# Will I receive things I stored in a polar station after returning from the expedition?

Tags: the-curious-expedition

In artic areas, there are polar station that provide, among other things, a storage room. If I leave something there, will I receive it after returning from the expedition?

If not, what are they even good for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been able to confirm that it functions just like the storage room at the Missionary and you receive the items you store there when returning to civilization.